# Woocommerce custom product dimensions for fedex

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In woocommerce I would like to be able to update the product dimensions based on a few selections by the user. I have been able to access these dimensions but when adding them to the product the shipping calculation uses the default dimensions rather than the updated values.

```
function add_shipping_dimensions( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id )
{
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $dimensions = explode('X', $cart_item_data['addons'][1]['value']);
    $width = $dimensions[0];
    $height = $dimensions[1];
    $product->set_width($width);
    $product->set_height($height);
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

I am using the **WooCommerce FedEx Shipping** plugin to calculate shipping costs for Fedex.

In short, how do I edit specific product dimensions so fedex will use the custom dimensions set in the code, rather than the default dimensions in wordpress?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Muhammad, Question edited to make it more clear